# Query works fine from phpMyAdmin but not from application (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, database-restore

There are a few similar questions on SO and elsewhere but mostly with php and I do not understand that. I'm trying to restore a database with a 62 tables like this:

```
string query = @"SET SQL_MODE= 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'; CREATE DATABASE " + dbName + " DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; USE " + dbName + ";" + Environment.NewLine;

using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("C:\b.sql"))
{
    string line = reader.ReadToEnd();
    query += line; //almost 1700 lines.
}
// upto this i get the query correctly which works fine in phpMyAdmin.

MySqlCommand c = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
c.ExecuteReader();
//but when I execute, throws: "Fatal error encountered during command execution."
```

Why is this so? If it's 'cos of the length of the query, then how can I execute such large queries from the application?

Comment: Are you using the same authentication information between myPHPAdmin and the MySqlConnection object?

Comment: Have you also tried just displaying the query in a MessageBox or to the console just to make sure it looks OK before it gets sent to the MySql Engine?

Comment: @Scott Vercuski I do not know what authentication information is. If it's the username and password, then yes.

Comment: Is your SQL script running a series of commands or returning a data set?  You do not want to use ExecuteReader() if no result sets are returned.

Comment: @Scott Vercuski, haha, good catch. Yes. I have seen the query. In fact it's the query string that I get from the code while debugging that I run in phpMyAdmin which works!! :(

Comment: @Jonathan.Peppers It is running a series of queries (1700 lines) - various create tables, drop tables, insert values etc. But yes the query isn't returning anything. I do not use any datasets. By the way, I tried ExecuteNonQuery as well which gives the same error. I did not try ExecuteScalar though. Lemme..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for check error:

```
List<string> query = new List<string>(){
        "SET SQL_MODE= 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';",
        string.Format("CREATE DATABASE `{0}` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;", dbName),
        string.Format("USE `{0}`;", dbName)}; // error string.Format("USE `{0}`;{1}", dbName)
/*    
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("C:\b.sql"))
{
    while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
        query.Add(reader.ReadLine());
}
*/

using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("C:\b.sql"))
{
    string lines = reader.ReadToEnd();
    string[] alines = lines.Split(';');
    foreach(string q in alines) 
            query.Add(q);
}

foreach (string command in query)
{
    try
    {
        using (MySqlCommand c = new MySqlCommand(command, conn))
        {
            c.ExecuteReader();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("OK Command: {0}", command));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error: {0}. Command: {1}", ex.Message, command));
        break;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

for better performance, you can use this class. I have not tried it, hope it works well:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace MySQLHelperTest
{
    public class MySQLTestingQuery
    {
        public MySqlConnection MyConnection { get; set; }
        public string FileSql { get; set; }
        public List<string> PreviousQuerys { get; set; }
        public List<string> CorrectQuerys { get; private set; }
        public string ErrorQuery { get; private set; }

        public MySQLTestingQuery()
        {
            this.CorrectQuerys = new List<string>();
            this.ErrorQuery = string.Empty;
        }

    public void Start()
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(this.FileSql);
        if (!file.Exists)
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("nonexistent file: '{0}'", this.FileSql));

        if (this.PreviousQuerys != null)
            foreach (string command in this.PreviousQuerys)
                this.RunMySQLCommand(command);

        try
        {
            foreach (string command in this.ReadQuerys(this.FileSql))
                Console.WriteLine(command);
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("an unexpected error happened: {0}. ", ex.Message));
        }

    }

        private void RunMySQLCommand(string command)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlCommand c = new MySqlCommand(command, this.MyConnection))
                {
                    c.ExecuteReader();
                    this.CorrectQuerys.Add(command);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.ErrorQuery = command;
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("error: {0}. command: {1}", ex.Message, command));
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<string> ReadQuerys(string file)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file)) 
            {
                string query = string.Empty;
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    query += (char)sr.Read();
                    if (query.EndsWith(";"))
                    {
                        yield return query;
                        query = string.Empty;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It did not work since I cant execute each query line by line. Some queries are split into many lines. Anyway thanks for enlightening me..

Comment: you can try this way, taking as limiting the querys the character ";"

Comment: Yes I could sense that. Let me see

Comment: In the update, not verified the use of comments `/ * ... * /`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a limit to the length of a query string for MySql. My first thought would be to break the giant 1700 line set of queries into individual queries.

```
string query = @"SET SQL_MODE= 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'; CREATE DATABASE " + dbName + " DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci" + Environment.NewLine;
MySqlCommand c;
c = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
c.ExecuteNonQuery();

using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("C:\b.sql"))
{
    string line = reader.ReadToEnd();
    query = "USE " + dbName + "; " + line;
    c = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    c.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This way you could create the database and then run each query individually. Without knowing your data this may help you pinpoint any issues. If you surrounded the "ExecuteNonQuery" with a try catch block you could catch any queries that fail and put them in a log file to look at when the batch is done.

Comment: He should also use `File.ReadAllText("C:\b.sql")`, not sure what the point of using StreamReader is.

Comment: @Jonathan.Peppers Very true, missed that point completely ... good catch !

Comment: @Jonathan.Peppers I did not know about such a reader. Let me try that. Very thanks..

Comment: Thats a better solution for this, but breaking 1700 lines of complex queries is too much to do so.. Simply there aint a solution I guess. An answer for this question better would be why I can execute it from phpMyAdmin but not from application..